# flutter forbid CupertinoTabView rebuild the widget not working

Tags: ios, flutter

In iOS ,the tabbar swith will not reload the loaded page.But in flutter it will reload when you click the tab.After searching many website, i got a solution of using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin. But it doesn't work.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.star), title: Text('Star')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text('Settings')),
      ]),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CupertinoTabView(
          builder: (context) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0:
                return Text1();
              case 1:
                return Text2();
              case 2:
                return Text3();
              default:
                return Text1();
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Text1State extends State<Text1> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('initState text1');
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    super.deactivate();
    print('deactivate text1');
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    print('dispose text1');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build text1');
    super.build(context);
    return Center(
      child: Text('text1'),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Fisrt i clicked the all three tab, and then when i click tab1 it shows

```
flutter: build text1
flutter: build text2
flutter: build text3
```

It sees all the tab pages rebuild again. So how to forbidden rebuild the page have loaded like the iOS tabbar.
Thank you.